# Creating a new collection from another collection

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, eloquent

im creating a collection of specific data from a query that i made, but i need to create a new collection with only some data with custom names properties, i was using arrays, but i need to make it in collections since is easyer to format the data and access some collections methods.

My current code is like:

```
    $activity = [];
            $temp = [];

$calculations = collect($user->calculations()
            ->withTrashed()
            ->orderBy('updated_at', 'desc')
            ->get());

        foreach($calculations as $calculation){
            $temp['type'] = "calculation";
            $temp['name'] = $calculation->name;
            $user = $this->getUserById($calculation->pivot->user_id);
            $temp['user'] = $user->name ." ".$user->surname;



            if($calculation->created_at == $calculation->updated_at && $calculation->deleted_at == null)
            {
                $temp['operation'] = "saved";
                $temp['date'] = $calculation->created_at;
                $temp['diff'] =  Carbon::parse($calculation->created_at)->diffForHumans();
            }elseif($calculation->created_at != $calculation->updated_at && $calculation->deleted_at != null)
            {

                $temp['operation'] = "changed";
                $temp['date'] = $calculation->updated_at;
                $temp['diff'] =  Carbon::parse($calculation->updated_at)->diffForHumans();

            }else{
                $temp['operation'] = "delete";
                $temp['date'] = $calculation->deleted_at;
                $temp['diff'] =  Carbon::parse($calculation->deleted_at)->diffForHumans();
            }


           array_push($activity,$temp);


        }
     $conditions = collect($user->conditions()
                ->withTrashed()
                ->orderBy('updated_at', 'desc')
                ->get());


            foreach($conditions as $condition){
                $temp['type'] = "condition";
                $temp['name'] = $condition->name;
                $user = $this->getUserById($condition->user_id);
                $temp['user'] = $user->name ." ".$user->surname;

                if($condition->created_at == $condition->updated_at && $condition->deleted_at == null)
                {
                    $temp['operation'] = "saved";
                    $temp['date'] = $condition->created_at;
                    $temp['diff'] =  Carbon::parse($condition->created_at)->diffForHumans();
                }elseif($condition->created_at != $condition->updated_at && $condition->deleted_at != null)
                {

                    $temp['operation'] = "alterado";
                    $temp['date'] = $condition->updated_at;
                    $temp['diff'] =  Carbon::parse($condition->updated_at)->diffForHumans();

                }else{
                    $temp['operation'] = "delete it";
                    $temp['date'] = $condition->deleted_at;
                    $temp['diff'] =  Carbon::parse($condition->deleted_at)->diffForHumans();
                }

                array_push($activity,$temp);
```

I already convert the eloquent query to "collect", but how i cant createa new collections, i need to instead using the array methods, i should use the collection methods to create them.

Basically my main reason is that i need to merge the "conditions" and "calculations" for than be able to order the dataTime the collections.

Comment: Query builder will already return a collection of results, so the starting `collect(query...)` is not really needed

Comment: What's wrong with above code?  I agree with @Pedro

Comment: Do you want to convert `$activity` array to `collection`?

Comment: @VaibhavrajRoham Nothing is really wrong. I'm just saying he's wrapping the result of both queries in `collect(result)` which is completely unneccessary since the query result will automatically be converted into a collection already.

Comment: Sorry @devk I was suppose to say that I agree with you. Sorry for typo

Answer (score 0):

How about something like this.

I've used `transform` method on collections (in order to transform the key names). I've replicated your logic and then merged both collections.

```
$calculations = $user->calculations()
        ->withTrashed()
        ->orderBy('updated_at', 'desc')
        ->get();

$transformed = $calculations->transform(function($item, $key) use($user) {
        $toReturn = [];
        $toReturn['type'] = "calculation";
        $toReturn['name'] = $item->name;
        $toReturn['user'] = $user->name;

        if($item->created_at == $item->updated_at && $item->deleted_at == null) {
            $toReturn['operation'] = "saved";
            $toReturn['date'] = $item->created_at;
            $toReturn['diff'] =  Carbon::parse($item->created_at)->diffForHumans();
        } elseif($item->created_at != $item->updated_at && $item->deleted_at != null){
            $toReturn['operation'] = "changed";
            $toReturn['date'] = $item->updated_at;
            $toReturn['diff'] =  Carbon::parse($item->updated_at)->diffForHumans();

        } else {
            $toReturn['operation'] = "delete";
            $toReturn['date'] = $item->deleted_at;
            $toReturn['diff'] =  Carbon::parse($item->deleted_at)->diffForHumans();
        }
        return $toReturn;
    });

 $conditions = $user->conditions()
            ->withTrashed()
            ->orderBy('updated_at', 'desc')
            ->get();

$transformed2 = $conditions->transform(function($item, $key) use($user) {
        $toReturn = [];
        $toReturn['type'] = "calculation";
        $toReturn['name'] = $item->name;
        $toReturn['user'] = $this->getUserById($item->user_id);

        if($item->created_at == $item->updated_at && $item->deleted_at == null) {
            $toReturn['operation'] = "saved";
            $toReturn['date'] = $item->created_at;
            $toReturn['diff'] =  Carbon::parse($item->created_at)->diffForHumans();
        } elseif($condition->created_at != $condition->updated_at && $condition->deleted_at != null){
            $toReturn['operation'] = "changed";
            $toReturn['date'] = $item->updated_at;
            $toReturn['diff'] =  Carbon::parse($item->updated_at)->diffForHumans();

        } else {
            $toReturn['operation'] = "delete";
            $toReturn['date'] = $item->deleted_at;
            $toReturn['diff'] =  Carbon::parse($item->deleted_at)->diffForHumans();
        }
        return $toReturn
    });

$merged = $transform->merge($transform2);
```

Comment: hello, thanks for your feedback, im getting a error of "
"Call to a member function getKey() on array""

Comment: Which line and which file?

Answer (score 0):

Building on @devk 's answer here is a neater version without so much repetitive code:

```
/**
 * Transform a collction with a given callback
 *
 * @param   Collection   $collection     A laravel collection
 * @param   User         $user           A User object
 * @return  Collection
 **/
private function transformCollection(Collect $collection, User $user) {
    return $collection->transform(function($item, $key) use ($user) {
        $toReturn = [
            'type' => 'calculation',
            'name' => $item->name,
            'user' => $user->name
        ];

        if ($item->created_at == $item->updated_at && $item->deleted_at == null) {
            $toReturn['operation']  = "saved";
            $toReturn['date']       = $item->created_at;
            $toReturn['diff']       = Carbon::parse($item->created_at)->diffForHumans();
        } elseif ($item->created_at != $item->updated_at && $item->deleted_at != null) {
            $toReturn['operation']  = "changed";
            $toReturn['date']       = $item->updated_at;
            $toReturn['diff']       = Carbon::parse($item->updated_at)->diffForHumans();
        } else {
            $toReturn['operation']  = "delete";
            $toReturn['date']       = $item->deleted_at;
            $toReturn['diff']       = Carbon::parse($item->deleted_at)->diffForHumans();
        }

        return $toReturn;
    });
}

// Return all user calculations ordered by when they were updated including deleted
$calculations   = $user->calculations()->withTrashed()->orderBy('updated_at', 'desc')->get();
$conditions     = $user->conditions()->withTrashed()->orderBy('updated_at', 'desc')->get();

// Transform both collections
$transformed    = transformCollection($calculations, $user);
$transformed2   = transformCollection($conditions, $user);

// Merge the resulting collections into a single collection
$merged = $transform->merge($transform2);
```

---

#### Edit

If your `Calculation` object has a model you can also make sure that the dates are returned as `Carbon` dates by adding them to the `protected $dates = []` array

```
protected $dates = [
    'deleted_at',
    'created_at',
    'updated_at'
];
```

I think that `created_at` and `updated_at` are included in this by default as part of `BaseModel`, thought i could well be wrong.